# python say isalpha() is not defined despite it being built in (I think)

Tags: python, python-3.x, isalpha

i am running a program that takes a list of numbers and letters, and separates the numbers into a sperate list and printing that list, but every time i run the code it says that isalpha is not defined.

```
yes = []
item=[1,7,-10,34,2,"a",-8]
for things in item:
    if isalpha() ==True:
        continue
    else:
        yes.append
        print(yes)
```

Comment: `isalpha` is a method on the `str` class. You would need something more along the lines of `if isinstance(things, str) and things.isalpha():`.

Comment: Did you mean `if str(things).isalpha():` and `yes.append(things)`?

Answer (score 1):

`isalpha()` is a method for the `str` class which returns `True` if all the characters inside a string are letters and `False` if that's not the case. Example:

```
>>> MyString = "fwUBCEFèfewf"
>>> MyString.isalpha()
True
>>> MyOtherString = "f13bbG"
>>> MyOtherString.isalpha()
False
```

In order to separate all the letters and numbers inside the item array you need to rewrite your code like this:

```
letters = []
numbers = []

item=[1,7,-10,34,2,"a",-8]
for things in item:
    if str(things).isalpha():
        letters.append(things)
    else:
        numbers.append(things)

print(letters)
print(numbers)

# output:
# ['a']
# [1, 7, -10, 34, 2, -8]
```

You will have to do `str(things)` inside the conditions because the `isalpha()` is only a function you can use on strings and not integers. If you don't add this you will get an error saying `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isalpha'`.

You could also do this if you use the `isinstance()` function to check wether `things` is a string or not. You would do it like this:

```
letters = []
numbers = []

item=[1,7,-10,34,2,"a",-8]
for things in item:
    if isinstance(things, str) and things.isalpha():
        letters.append(things)
    else:
        numbers.append(things)

print(letters)
print(numbers)

# output:
# ['a']
# [1, 7, -10, 34, 2, -8]
```

Since the letters can only be strings you can check if the `things` is of type `str` with the `isinstance()` function. Here two conditions have to be `True`.

I hope that I could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

[`.isalpha`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/isalpha) is a method not a function <sup>(see [this tutorial](https://techvidvan.com/tutorials/python-methods-vs-functions/) to learn more about the difference)</sup>, so it cannot be called by name. I think you want

```py
    if str(things).isalpha(): continue
```

or

```py
    if isinstance(things, str) and things.isalpha(): 
        continue
```

Also, the `else` is not necessary after `continue`, so you can follow with **`yes.append(things)`** <sup>(not just *`yes.append`*)</sup>:

```py
yes = []
item=[1,7,-10,34,2,"a",-8]
for things in item:
    if isinstance(things, str) and things.isalpha(): 
        continue
    yes.append(things)
    print(yes)
```

(But why are you printing `yes` [potentially on repeat] inside the loop instead of after the loop?)

---

Alternately you could just use [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension) <sup>([view output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBaMj.png))</sup>

```py
item=[1,7,-10,34,2,"a",-8]
yes = [i for i in item if not (isinstance(i, str) and i.isalpha())] 
print(*yes, sep='\n')
```